# Android Fragment Type Mismatch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, types

I am new to android and am following the tutorial at Dartmouth. http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture08/lecture08.html

I am following all the codes and at the MainActivity.java,

```
// create the fragments
Fragment mFindFragment = new FindFragment();
Fragment mChatFragment = new ChatFragment();

// bind the fragments to the tabs - set up tabListeners for each tab 
mFindTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mFindFragment,
                           getApplicationContext()));
mChatTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mChatFragment,
                           getApplicationContext()));
```

I have encountered this error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from FindFragment to Fragment. So I follow the fix error suggestions and change the code to

```
// create the fragments
FindFragment mFindFragment = new FindFragment();

// bind the fragments to the tabs - set up tabListeners for each tab 
mFindTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mFindFragment,
                           getApplicationContext()));
```

Now, there is a new error: The constructor MyTabsListener(FindFragment, Context) is undefined.

Just in case the imports are critical, here they are:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

For myTabsListener:

```
  class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;
    public Context context;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

}
```

For my FindFragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FindFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.findfragment, container, false);
    }


}
```

I am pretty confused here. I am not sure if this is related to my import, lib setup or other problems. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the code of your `MyTabsListener` class. Make sure your class `MyTabsListener` contains constructor with the two parameters which you have defined.

Comment: What does your activity extend and post the imports of fragment

Comment: Please show `MyTabsListener` and `FindFragment` class. You should either `extends Fragment` for `FindFragment` class or change the constructor of MyTabsListener to `MyTabsListener(FindFragment ff, Context c)`

Comment: In which class your have written the code `mChatTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mChatFragment,getApplicationContext()));`? Is it activity of Fragment ? Please show it.

Comment: post the tab listener

Comment: and the imports for the same

Comment: do you have `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` any where??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
// you will use this import when you want fragment from support library 
// in that case you will extend FragmentActivity which is the base class for support based fragments
```

to

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

in `FindFragment.java`.

Similarly do the same in `ChatFragment.java` also

Comment: Thanks it is working now! I am just wondering so if i use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; then i need to use FragmentActivity; and if i use import android.app.Fragment, then i will need to use Fragment. and i can use either pair right?

Comment: @JeffLam you need to use support based fragments below 11. Note fragments were introduced in api level 11. And for backward compatibility if needed you will use fragments from support library